# How to apply a "OR" in a ElasticSearch query finding in a multiple fields

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, search, text

I have an ElasticSearch implemented, in this moment I have an index with a Product.

```
    public class SkuSearchModel
    {
        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<string> CategoriesNames { get; set; }
    }
```

And have this implementation seaching by ProductName

```
    _elasticClient.SearchAsync<Product>(search =>
    {
    search.Query(query => query
            .Bool(@bool =>
            {
                @bool.Must(query => query
            .Match(match => match
            .Field(product => product.ProductName)
            .Query("text")
            )
        );
            })
        );
    });
```

The question is, how I can add an OR in the query and search by ProductName, ProductDescription or CategoriesNames. I tried the following ways but they didn't work for me.

```
    _elasticClient.SearchAsync<Product>(search =>
    {
    search.Query(query => query
            .Bool(@bool =>
            {
                @bool.Must(query => query
            .Match(match => match
            .Field(product => product.ProductName)
                        .Field(product => product.ProductDescription)
                        .Field(product => product.CategoriesNames)
            .Query("text")
            )
        );
            })
        );
    });


    _elasticClient.SearchAsync<Product>(search =>
    {
    search.Query(query => query
            .Bool(@bool =>
            {
                @bool.Must(query => query
            .MultiMatch(match => match
                        .Fields("ProductName")
                        .Fields("ProductDescription")
                        .Fields("ProductName")
            .Query("text")
            )
        );
            })
        );
    });
```

I would appreciate your help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be some syntax errors in your query.

Try below

```
var response = _elasticClient.SearchAsync<SkuSearchModel>(search =>
                      search.Query(query => query
                                      .Bool(@bool =>
                                          @bool.Must(query => query
                                               .MultiMatch(match => match
                                                                    .Fields(fs => fs
                                                                                     .Field(p => p.ProductName)
                                                                                     .Field(p => p.ProductDescription)
                                                                                     .Field(p => p.CategoriesNames)
                                                                            )
                                                                   .Query("text")
                                                      )
                                                    )
                                      )
                                  )
                 ).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

You can use below query to get actual dsl query to try out in kibana

Set  .EnableDebugMode() in connection string

```
var res1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.ApiCall.RequestBodyInBytes);

{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "fields": [
              "productName",
              "productDescription",
              "categoriesNames"
            ],
            "query": "abc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @AgustínMendoza If it resolved your problem . Please mark as answer

Comment: Sorry the delay, thank you very much!